# How I can copy a src code from my computer to the remote computer

Tags: command-line, permissions, ssh, compiling, make

I am beginner in linux and I don't know many details about it.
I am trying to copy a folder from my computer to remote computer to install it in the remote computer and work with it. how I can do that.

I tried with this command

```
gouda@tm24j:~$ scp /src gouda@csopt1
cp: cannot stat `/src': No such file or directory
```

Also, I tried

```
gouda@tm24j:~$ scp /src/to/local/dir gouda@csopt1:/path/to/remote/dir
gouda@csopt1's password: 
/src/to/local/dir: No such file or directory

gouda@tm24j:~$ scp /src gouda@csopt1:/path/to/remote/dir
gouda@csopt1's password: 
/src: No such file or directory

gouda@tm24j:~$ scp src gouda@csopt1
cp: omitting directory `src'
```

please note that src file is in my home directory

```
gouda@tm24j:~/src$ pwd
/home/gouda/src
```

Thank you

Comment: Is `src` a file or a directory?  Where are you executing the `scp` from, your home directory or the `src` folder?  (Refer to your `pwd` before you execute the `scp` command to answer the last one)

Comment: src is a file contain my code in my home directory . I tried to copy it from home directory not from inside src file.

Comment: is it a *single* file or a *directory* containing many different files comprising your source code?

Comment: it is a directory contain many files. and I succeed to to copy it inside the remore computer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you try to copy `/src` it shows that the file does not exist because if a path starts with a slash, it is treated as *absolute path*. That means it is treated as relative to the file system root `/`.

Simply omit the `/` at the beginning of the local path and don't forget to specify a path on the target computer, like this (running from inside your home directory):

```
scp src gouda@csopt1:/home/gouda/src-copy
```

(Thanks to *@ThomasWard*) if your `src` is a directory, you need to enable `scp`'s recursive mode by adding the `-r` flag:

```
scp -r src gouda@csopt1:/home/gouda/src-copy
```

Comment: I think you're missing the `-r` flag here for 'recursive' for the recursive copy of the directory.

Comment: I tried through the local computer and it doesn't suceed,gouda@tm24j:~/src$ scp src gouda@csopt1:/home/gouda/src-copy
gouda@csopt1's password: 
src: No such file or directory

Comment: @user3076763 My command example was assuming you were running it from inside your home directory `~` (same as `/home/gouda`). If you run it from inside the folder you want to copy, replace `src` with a simple period (`.`) which means the current directory: `scp -r . gouda@csopt1:/home/gouda/src-copy`

Comment: If the answer now solves your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey round check button on its left. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

I was trying to make a copy for the file from inside the file not from outside and this was t